# Why does Vlookup not working with another workbook?

Tags: excel

I am trying to use Vlookup from another sheet

=VLOOKUP(C11,[C1]Sheet1!A1:C3,3) gives me random Values.

where[C1] contains a path to another workbook
and C11 contains the value to be looked up.
However, when I use a sheet in the same workbook and use the above formula it works properly.

=VLOOKUP(C11,Sheet2!A1:C3,3)

The data in the cells is as follows:
ColA    ColB     ColC
A blank    1
B blank    2
C blank    3

Comment: You're referring to Sheet1 in the first formula, and Sheet2 in the second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLOOKUP requieres a fourth parameter which is TRUE or FALSE. The default value is TRUE if you enter nothing. Then Excel will pick the most similar value. If you put FALSE only the exact value will be used.